# Experience manager not showing add new promotions

Tags: smarttarget, sdl-tridion, web8.5, experience-optimization

I have setup the experience manager and query service and registred in discovery, completed the steps [mentioned in the document](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-050EAC54-E634-4FB5-8451-EEADA5288BD5.xml&docid=GUID-050EAC54-E634-4FB5-8451-EEADA5288BD5&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-050EAC54-E634-4FB5-8451-EEADA5288BD5&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DSmartTargetDeploymentWebService&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1490000330118&currentQuery=SmartTargetDeploymentWebService&currentScope=), but my screen is just showing as loading when I click on Targeting, nothing is loading as below .. am I missing something???

[image: not able to create promotions]

Comment: Neither XPM nor the query service are involved when you load that page. Instead, it uses the Content Manager, Topology Manager, and the Management service to render the list. It looks like it is breaking before it even figures out which environments are available, so that would mean the problem is either client-side or in the communication with the CM/TTM. You should check your browser console and the Event Viewer for errors.

Comment: I just ran the Content manager setup again with repair mode, and it got worked..!!!

Comment: I'm guessing your previous mishap with installing the wrong version is to blame. Anyway, please do consider providing 'repair' as an answer in case anyone else runs into it in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by running setup again with repair mode